# How do I override classes in jquery UI?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm trying to style my jquery UI Slider ".unlock-slider" handle freely using css. All solutions that I found on google told me to use !important or to change the css that comes with UI directly. But that just does not seem like an elegant solution to me. 
The UI Documentation tells me how to override (does that mean "overwrite" btw?) the CSS framework: [Slider theming](https://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#theming) using the [classes option](http://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/widget-factory/classes-option/).

So I tried to do it that way but something seems to be off and I don't know what it is. The script does not override the UI class with my custom class.

I'm quite new to this all so sorry if there are total beginners' mistakes.

This slider is the only reason to make use of jquery UI btw. So if there is another way to make a slider I'm happy to try it out!

Thanks a lot

EDIT: Found a typo. Now the class applies BUT it does not override the attributes of the existing UI css. See
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6huA4.png):

Code:

```js
 var slider = $( ".unlock-slider").slider({
    classes: {
      "ui-slider-handle": "custom-handle"
    }
  });
 $(".unlock-slider").slider
 ({
   max:50 });
});
```

```css
.custom-handle {
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: tomato;
}
```

```html
  <div class="slider-wrapper">
                <div class="unlock-slider">
                </div>
              </div>
```

Comment: Mybe it's a typo but your selector is wrong, It should be ".unlock-slider".

Comment: Wow, thanks. I've just stared at this for to long, I suppose. That did solve the problem of the class not applying at all. There's still another problem, I will edit this and add to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understand your issue. Making some suggestions:

```js
var slider = $(".unlock-slider").slider({
  classes: {
    "ui-slider-handle": "custom-handle"
  },
  max:50
});
```

```css
.unlock-slider span.custom-handle {
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="slider-wrapper">
  <div class="unlock-slider">
  </div>
</div>
```

If your theming is not be read, or overwritten, be more specific in your definition.

Comment: Hey, what did you do there with "span.custom-handle"? The issue is that the slider still looks like the predefined jquery UI css. I want to make my own handle, so detatch or rather overwrite the css that comes with jquery UI. But as the image shows, when I try to define CSS properties that are already defined differently in the jquery UI css they simply won't apply.

Comment: I suggest that you check exactly which classes are applied and try to override those classes. Maybe you missed one.

Comment: @Moheri the slider creates a `span` element with your class. So you can use a more specific selector in your css and this will ensure it is used. Try running the code snippet, you'll see a round handle in tomato color.

Comment: Thank you so much! This solved it for me. To get rid of the dark outline, I would need to alter the :active pseudo class, right? Just as a hint in the right direction

Comment: You could try that. Will check.

Comment: @Moheri jQuery UI adds a class: `ui-state-active` You can adjust the theme for this class in a similar manner: `.unlock-slider span.ui-state-active`